# Different Language for Frontend vs Backend

Tags: translation

I use an English WordPress package and this is very well.

Now, I would like to translate some elements of the blog (like "posted on", "comments") etc., but do leave the dashboard interface intact in English.

Is there any mechanism to translate just the site elements?

Answer (score 21):

You can do the following:

1. Get the the language pack (e.g. `de_DE.mo`) from [wordpress.org](http://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_in_Your_Language). If the language pack isn't available as a standalone download, you could also use the `.mo` file which is bundled in the WordPress ZIP-file for your language. Located under `wp-content/languages`.
2. Move the `.mo` file to `wp-content/languages/` of your default (english) WordPress installation.
3. Change the `WPLANG` constant in `wp-config.php` to the new locale (e.g. `de_DE`)
4. In your `functions.php` add the following filter:

**functions.php**

```
add_filter('locale', 'wpse27056_setLocale');
function wpse27056_setLocale($locale) {
    if ( is_admin() ) {
        return 'en_US';
    }

    return $locale;
}
```

Comment: now, what do you mean by "install your language pack"? should I uninstall the wordpress, and install the new wordpress, but say French? I don't want to uninstall my English wordpress.

Comment: No, you don't have to reinstall anything. Just download WP in your desired language an copy the language file from `wp-content/languages/` to your original english WP install and modify `wp-config.php` as described above. Or just download the `fr_FR.mo` file from [this site](http://www.wordpress-fr.net/telechargements/).

Comment: I had not the `wp-content/languages/` folder, so I should create it. After performing that manipulation, I has the vice-versa of what I would. I have now the admin panel in Romanian, but the page (even logged or not) - in English. Perhaps I should translate the theme...

Comment: Of course, you need the theme translated. But the backend should be in English not Romanian if you set `is_admin()` in the filter above.

Comment: I added this code at the end of the functions.php file of the current (twenty ten) theme... Is that correct?

Comment: Jep.. doesn't work? Any plugins installed?

Comment: I have code based on this, putting it in a themes `functions.php` isn't going to work as it's too late. I placed it in an mu-plugin and saw vastly improved results.

Comment: this doesn't work

Comment: didn't work for me either.

Comment: see also my answer bellow for the WordPress v >= 4.7, that allows users to see the Backend in their own language

Answer (score 16):

**Since WordPress version 4.7**, different **Backend users** can set their *own preferred admin language* using the *native* WordPress language selector. This way, they see the WordPress interface in their language and can more easily manage content.
[image: Different language for Backend users in Wordpress independent of the Frontend language]

Comment: The code sets that for all users globally, this works only on an individual account.

Answer (score 10):

In the WordPress 5.x it real simple to get a different frond and back end language

To change the site language go to Setting -> General -> Site Language and select the site language.

[image]

For the Admin Panel goto Users -> Your Profile and select the language you want to have on the Admin Panel

[image]

So all the above solutions have become absolute, each user can set their own language for the WordPress interface

Comment: This should be the selected answer for 2019+. No plugins required and the solution is so simple. Thank you!

Comment: This change it per each user individually, the code will change it automatically to all users.

Answer (score 6):

You can use plugins for that:
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/kau-boys-backend-localization/
or
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-native-dashboard/

Comment: Welcome to our site. Please add an explanation: What do these plugins, what are the differences?

Comment: I think there are doing exactly the same. (I just use the first one...) You can install different language files and with the plugins you can change the language for the backend independently. Both plugins provide Dashboard switches for the language, a login language select box and an add-on to the profile page for user-specific language.

Answer (score 4):

If anyone is still looking for that, here is what you should do since version 4.7

```
function wp_noshor_redefine_locale($locale) {
    if( is_admin() ):
        switch_to_locale('en_US');
    endif;
}
add_filter('init','wp_noshor_redefine_locale');
```

This forces the dashboard to load in English, then you can go to settings, set the language you desire.

Answer (score 2):

**An updated answer for Wordpress 4+**

[@rofflox's answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/27065/17826) is still correct, but there have been some changes to Wordpress that can have an effect when using his function 'as-is' since WP 4.0.

The wp-config constant [`WPLANG` has been deprecated](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/changeset/29630) in favour of setting the site language via a dropdown in `Settings->General`. This means that, after changing your site's language to **Svenka** (for example), your site's admin *will* appear in English... but that Site Language dropdown in `Settings->General` will be pre-selected as **English (United States)**. That means that, if you make changes to your General settings later on and forget to pick **Svenka** as your site's language again, the whole site will revert back to English.

I would recommend creating functions in your `functions.php` file like so:

```
//    Set the locale; original function from @rofflox

function vnmFunctionality_setLocale($locale) {
    if (is_admin()) {
        return 'en_US';
    }

    return $locale;
}

add_filter('locale', 'vnmFunctionality_setLocale');

// Enqueue a script to force-set the Language dropdown on the General Options page, just in case we forget about it later.

function vnmFunctionality_countryReminderScript($hook) {
    if ($hook != 'options-general.php') {
        return;
    }

    wp_enqueue_script('lang-reminder-script', get_template_directory() . '/js/site-language.js', array('jquery'), '1.0.0', true);

    wp_localize_script('lang-reminder-script', 'langObject', array(
        'lang'  => get_option('WPLANG'),
    ));
}

add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', 'vnmFunctionality_countryReminderScript');
```

And then a Javascript file called `site-language.js` (saved in a `/js/` folder in your theme) like so:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('select#WPLANG').val(langObject.lang).change();
});
```

This should automatically pre-select the site's current display language in the dropdown on the Options page, so that you don't have to remember to do it manually every time.

Answer (score -1):

What you need is to translate your theme. If  your theme has a .pot file then it is easy to translate. Just follow the steps at

http://www.appthemes.com/blog/how-to-translate-a-wordpress-theme/

Else, you will need to edit the theme files and change the words at each instance.

Comment: my theme (twenty ten) has the folder "wp-content/themes/twentyten/languages" and there are only a .pot file inside...