# Change language of comments template

Tags: comments, translation, localization

I have a Wordpress installation in italian, I need to keep italian for the admin section but the frontend needs to be in english. The theme is custom so that's ok, but in single posts I'm using `comments_template()` which prints its output in italian.

I have read [this question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/27056/different-language-for-frontend-and-backend) but adding that filter seems to have no effect.

Is there anything else I need to do to change `comments_template()` language?

Comment: Any progress? Was my answer helpful?

Answer (score 1):

There are two options:

1. Replace all default strings for the comment form. Look at `wp-includes/comment-template.php` for available filters (there are *many*).
2. Set your blog's default language to English, install the [plugin WP Native Dashboard](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-native-dashboard/), load the Italian language files and set the admin language to Italian.

Here is a screen shot of the plugin settings:

[image]