# Localization: I want the backend: english and frontend in defined language

Tags: customization, multi-language, front-end, translation, localization

I'd like to have the backend of Wordpress in English and use a different locale for the frontend

so far I figure out perhaps I could do it by setting in the wpconfig the locale I want to use in the frontend, then add in functions.php something like this:

```
add_filter('locale', 'mytheme_backendlocale');
function mytheme_backendlocale($locale) {
    if ( is_admin() ) {
        return 'en_US';
    }
    return $locale;
}
```

is this the best practice to achieve what I want or should I do it differently?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install the plugin [WP Native Dashboard](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-native-dashboard/). Then you can set one language for the front-end in your `wp-config.php` and each user can choose another one for the back-end.
See [Change language of comments template](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/52538/73) for details and a screenshot.

Answer (score 1):

There is a plugin that may be what you need.

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/fe-be-localization/

Comment: well thanks, I'll give a look to the code, but maybe won't use it since it's not updated since 2008 and supports up to WP 2.6 only - if I like it and have the ability maybe will try to talk to the developer and update it

Comment: oh just checked, it does pretty much the same as the function I wrote above, in another style

Comment: Yeah, its old, but seems the only one around. If the code is how you have done it, then I guess the answer is you are on the correct track and its how I would have done it.. cant think of a better way.

Answer (score 1):

Till now, I think that Fulvio's answer's the best one. I'm using that filter even on a multisite setup, with just one line:

```
add_filter('locale', 'set_admin_locale');
function set_admin_locale($locale) {
  return 'en_US';
}
```

Basically sometimes, and in this case, I use multisite for multi-language sites instead of plugins. Also, I have 1 single theme for each language (usually child themes of the main language). So every site of the network has its own language, but on the admin side, I need all teh interfaces in italian.

So what I do is:

1. I don't use the general WPLANG constant in wp-config.php
2. I set italian in every site of teh network
3. In each theme's functions.php I use the above filter to control the frontend language/locale.

NOTE: that filter won't change the admin language, so there's no need to check if is_admin()

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is still looking for that, here is what you should do since version 4.7

```
function wp_noshor_redefine_locale($locale) {
    if( is_admin() ):
        switch_to_locale('en_US');
    endif;
}
add_filter('init','wp_noshor_redefine_locale');
```

This forces the dashboard to load in English, then you can go to settings, set the language you desire.