# Website in one language, but admin backend in English

Tags: language

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Localization: I want the backend: english and frontend in defined language](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/32584/localization-i-want-the-backend-english-and-frontend-in-defined-language)

I have installed WordPress in Greek language, because I need the greek frontend translation.
But I dont like the Greek admin backend.

Is there anyway to change only the backend language leaving the frontend untouched?