# how to have __() translating in languages different from admin?

Tags: multisite, admin, multi-language, localization

I use native wordpress multisite for languages (it, en, fr, de, es). I need not to use a plugin.

Still, all the admin dashboards will be in italian, because editors are all italian people. I know __() and related functions get the translation language from the WPLANG constant, but WPLANG also affects admin languange.

I'd like to get frontend in different languages while admin always italian. Is it possible?

Comment: Go and have a look at this [answer](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/27065/31545). You should be able to make it work for multisite. Hope this help

Answer (score 2):

Filter `locale` if `is_admin()` is `TRUE`:

```
is_admin() && add_filter( 'locale', function() {
    return 'it_IT';
});
```